# UIDatePicker - allow selecting time within two ranges

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

In our app we have a `UIDatePicker`, set to mode `Time`.
This date picker is user to let the user select a time for Take Away orders.

Take away orders can only be made within specific time ranges each day, for this we use the properties `minimumDate` and `maximumDate`. Now we want to make it so that the user can select a time in either of two different ranges. Let's say, orders are allowed for `09:00 - 12:00` and `13:00 - 17:00`, the picker should only allow those times to be selected.

As far as I can see, this is not possible by default, since the properties I use now are just singular time objects, not ranges. A solution could be to implement is manually, but there doesn't seem to be a `delegate` available for `UIDatePicker`.

What I'm wondering is, does someone know of a good, clean way to implement such functionality, while still using `UIDatePicker`, and not `UIPickerView`.

A good option would be if it has a delegate method such as `canSelectDate(_:) -> Bool`, which animates it back to the previous value if `false`. In here I could determine it using the ranges.

Comment: Why don't you use two date pickers?

Comment: That seems a bit overkill. The whole idea is to have just one picker that does all. There can be cases with 3 or 4 intervals, we don't want to have multiple pickers while there's just one time you can select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can react to changes of the picker like this:

`picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyViewController.pickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)`

And then your function looks like this:

```
@objc
private func pickerChanged(_ picker: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateIsAtLunchtime = picker.date >= lunchStart && picker.date <= lunchEnd
    if dateIsAtLunchtime {
        picker.setDate(lunchEnd, animated: true)
    }
}
```

If you have your dates defined like this:

```
let morningComponents = DateComponents(calendar: .current, hour: 8, minute: 0)
var morning: Date { return morningComponents.date ?? Date() }
let lunchStartComponents = DateComponents(calendar: .current, hour: 12, minute: 30)
var lunchStart: Date { return lunchStartComponents.date ?? Date() }
let lunchEndComponents = DateComponents(calendar: .current, hour: 14, minute: 30)
var lunchEnd: Date { return lunchEndComponents.date ?? Date() }
let eveningComponents = DateComponents(calendar: .current, hour: 18, minute: 0)
var evening: Date { return eveningComponents.date ?? Date() }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good and acceptable solution. I'll use this.